# Excel: How to write z=f(x,y) for different values of (x,y)

Tags: excel, function, variables

Anyone can help me with this problem?
I would like a way to write a formula z=f(x,y) and tell excel to calculate the value of that formula for different sets of the couple (x,y).

Or I could do this but I don't know how:

```
CELL 1:x^2+y^2,x=A1,y=A2
CELL 2:x^2+y^2,x=B1,y=B2
CELL 3:x^2+y^2,x=C1,y=C2
etc...
```

How can I do?
Thanks in advance for your precious help

Comment: If the set (X,Y) are consecutive values you can use Data Table

Comment: Could you just:   CELL 1: `=POWER(A1, 2) + POWER(A2, 2)` and copy it down the rows?

Comment: Thanks for the help but the function POWER is valid for this example. If i have complex formulas, I need a general way to calculate several z values using couples of (X,Y)

Comment: @yass can you tell me how to use data table please?
Thank you both

Comment: Understood how to use Data Table. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm entirely clear on what you need, so here's my response to what I think you're asking. Why not put all x's in one column, y's in the next column, and then have the function(s) in the subsequent columns? Then you can input the formula in the function column and drag it down. If you need to have the results appear together in the resultant (x,y) format, consider concatenating the next column. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

- In A1 first value of X
- In A2 First value of Y
- In A3 =the formula(X,Y) In a way Excel can calculate it like in your question:
  `=A1^2+A2^2`
- In B3 -->F3 for example write X values
- In A4 -->A10 for example write Y values
- Select A3:F10 Clickon `Data Table` in Data Tab
- In Row Input Cell write A1
- In Column Input Cell write A2
- Click Ok
  You will have all the values in an Array

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick support and help. It is a nice community.
I solved the problem using data table, as suggested.
You can find a link to the picture showing what I wanted to get.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jo0.png)